# How to change colsums and sum to loop in a formula?

Tags: r, loops, sum

I have a vector named `y` which has `n` numerical elements and a matrix `n*n` named `w` where its elements are numbers. I want to use the below formula for the above data:
[image]
I have written the following code in R using functions `colSums` and `sum`:

```
dy<-y-mean(y)
n*(y-mean(y))*colSums(w*dy)/sum(dy^2)#=local[,1]
```

Now, I want to change my above code to write it with `for` loop (without using `colSums` and `sum`). Indeed, I want to make the formula using `for` loop instead of using colSums and `sum`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use a `for`-loop since in this case there are many disadvantages, but here we go.

First we calculate the donominator:

```r
dy_square_sum <- 0

for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  dy_square_sum <- dy_square_sum + dy[i]^2
}
```

In the next step, we calculate the enumerator and build up your desired output:

```r
weighted_sum <- rep(0,n)
output <- rep(0, n)

for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  for (j in seq_along(y)) {
    weighted_sum[i] <- weighted_sum[i] + w[j,i] * dy[j]
  }
  output[i] <- n * dy[i] / dy_square_sum * weighted_sum[i]
}
```

or a little simplified but less efficient

```r
output <- rep(0, n)
for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  for (j in seq_along(y)) {
    output[i] <- output[i] + n * dy[i] * w[j,i] * dy[j] / dy_square_sum 
  }
}
```